# How to create two scenes in scalafx

Tags: scene, scalafx

I am new to creating GUI using scalafx. I am trying to create two scenes with the following code but getting some error

```
import com.sun.glass.ui.Application
import scalafx.event.ActionEvent
import scalafx.event.EventHandler
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.control.Button
import scalafx.scene.control.Label
import scalafx.scene.layout.StackPane
import scalafx.scene.layout.VBox
import scalafx.stage.Stage



class example extends Application {
  var scene1: Scene = null
  var scene2: Scene = null
  override def start(primaryStage: Stage): Unit =  { primaryStage.setTitle("My First JavaFX GUI")
    //Scene 1
    val label1 = new Label("This is the first scene")
    val button1 = new Button("Go to scene 2"){
      onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => {
        primaryStage.setScene(scene2)
      }
    }
    val layout1 = new VBox(20)
    layout1.getChildren.addAll(label1, button1)
    scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 300, 250)


    //Scene 2
    val label2 = new Label("This is the second scene")
    val button2 = new Button("Go to scene 1") {
      onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => {
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1)
      }
    }
    val layout2 = new VBox(20)
    layout2.getChildren.addAll(label2, button2)
    scene2 = new Scene(layout2, 300, 250)

    primaryStage.setScene(scene1)
    primaryStage.show()
  }
}

The error is:
 found   : scalafx.event.ActionEvent => Unit
[error]  required: javafx.event.EventHandler[javafx.event.ActionEvent]
[error]       onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => {}
```

How can I declare the action events to switch between the scenes?

It would be really helpful if anyone can help

Answer (score 1):

In ScaleFX, your first troubleshooting is to check if you included the ScaleFX implicit conversion magic:

```scala
import scalafx.Includes._
```

In your case, that will fix the issue with the action handler.

Additionally, you should not use `com.sun` packages neither in ScalaFX nor in JavaFX code. In ScalaFX you should use `JFXApp3` instead. Here is your code corrected to use `JFXApp3` with some minor corrections:

```scala
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp3
import scalafx.application.JFXApp3.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.event.{ActionEvent, EventHandler}
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.control.{Button, Label}
import scalafx.scene.layout.VBox
import scalafx.stage.Stage

object CreteTwoScenes1App extends JFXApp3 {
  var scene1: Scene = _
  var scene2: Scene = _

  override def start(): Unit = {

    stage = new PrimaryStage {
      title = "My First JavaFX GUI"
    }

    // Scene 1
    val label1 = new Label("This is the first scene")
    val button1 = new Button("Go to scene 2") {
      onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => {
        stage.setScene(scene2)
      }
    }
    val layout1 = new VBox(20)
    layout1.children ++= Seq(label1, button1)

    scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 300, 250)

    // Scene 2
    val label2 = new Label("This is the second scene")
    val button2 = new Button("Go to scene 1") {
      onAction = (e: ActionEvent) => {
        stage.setScene(scene1)
      }
    }
    val layout2 = new VBox(20)
    layout2.children ++= Seq(label2, button2)
    scene2 = new Scene(layout2, 300, 250)

    stage.setScene(scene1)
  }
}
```

You can also rewrite that in more idiomatic ScalaFX builder style. Using Scala 3 can make it much more compact too (no curly braces needed):

```scala
import scalafx.Includes.*
import scalafx.application.JFXApp3
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.control.{Button, Label}
import scalafx.scene.layout.VBox

object CreteTwoScenes2App extends JFXApp3:

  override def start(): Unit =
    lazy val scene1: Scene = new Scene(300, 200):
      root = new VBox(20):
        children = Seq(
          new Label("This is the first scene"),
          new Button("Go to scene 2"):
            onAction = () => stage.setScene(scene2)
        )

    lazy val scene2: Scene = new Scene(300, 200):
      root = new VBox(20):
        children = Seq(
          new Label("This is the second scene"),
          new Button("Go to scene 1"):
            onAction = () => stage.setScene(scene2)
        )

    stage = new JFXApp3.PrimaryStage:
      title = "My First JavaFX GUI"
      scene = scene1
```